# I can't transfer data from a screen to a list, I tried hive, but I was unable to compose the data structure, as it did not generate the g.dart file

Tags: list, flutter, dart, flutter-hive

family of programmers. I'm new to programming, I'm having a hard time transferring data from a screen to a list, where the user can review the messages sent. Sorry for this one with a silly question like that, but I already tried it in the library, videos and etc. But I did not find the solution, please, could someone help me with this? Thanks! (I've been stuck on this issue for days).

My code:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:animated_text_kit/animated_text_kit.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:animated_button/animated_button.dart';
import 'package:giffy_dialog/giffy_dialog.dart';
import 'package:mailer/mailer.dart';
import 'package:mailer/smtp_server/gmail.dart'; 
import 'package:ouvidoria_mvl/main.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class PaginadeBoasVindasAN extends StatelessWidget {

  String _localAn;
  String _problemaAn;
  File _imagemAn;
  File _imagemGaleriaAn;

  PaginadeBoasVindasAN(
    this._localAn,
    this._problemaAn,
    this._imagemAn,
    this._imagemGaleriaAn,
  );
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  // Aqui vamos criar o e-mail - smtp

  enviarMensagem() async {
    String username = '@gmail.com';
    String password = '4#';
    

    final smtpServer = gmail(username, password);
    // Use the SmtpServer class to configure an SMTP server:
    // final smtpServer = SmtpServer('smtp.domain.com');
    // See the named arguments of SmtpServer for further configuration
    // options.

    // Create our message.
    final message = Message()
      ..from = Address('', '')
      ..recipients.add('@gmail.com')
      ..ccRecipients.addAll(['destCc1@gmail.com', 'destCc1@gmail.com'])
      ..bccRecipients.add(Address('destCc1@gmail.com'))
      ..subject = '$_localAn :: ${DateTime.now()}'
      ..text = 'LOCAL DA OCORRÊNCIA: $_localAn,n\ OCORRÊNCIA: $_problemaAn';
      if ((_imagemAn != null) && (_imagemAn != ""))
       message.attachments.add(FileAttachment(_imagemAn,));
     if ((_imagemGaleriaAn!= null) && (_imagemGaleriaAn!= ""))
       message.attachments.add(FileAttachment(_imagemGaleriaAn,));
    try {
      final sendReport = await send(message, smtpServer);
      print('Mensagem enviada: ' + sendReport.toString());
    } on MailerException catch (e) {
      print('Mensagem não enviada.');
      for (var p in e.problems) {
        print('Problema: ${p.code}: ${p.msg}');
      }
    }
    var connection = PersistentConnection(smtpServer);

    await connection.send(message);

    await connection.close();
  }

// HERE THE APP CONFIGURATION IS ENDED

  // The Function below blocks the screen rotation, thus allowing the app to stay in vertical mode

  void blockgiro() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
        [DeviceOrientation.portraitDown, DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    blockgiro();
    return Stack(children: <Widget>[
      Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
            child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 1,
                            bottom: 10,
                            top: 10,
                          ),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          height: 200,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow(
                                    blurRadius: 0,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    offset: Offset(0, 0))
                              ],
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13),
                              color: Colors.white),
                          child:
                              Image.asset("Assets/image/enviando-loading.gif")),
                      Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                bottom: 30, right: 1, left: 1, top: 20),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 1,
                              bottom: 10,
                              top: 5,
                            ),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                      blurRadius: 2,
                                      color: Colors.black54,
                                      offset: Offset(1, 1))
                                ],
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13),
                                color: Colors.white),
                            child: Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                              child: SizedBox(
                                width: 250.0,
                                child: TypewriterAnimatedTextKit(
                                  pause: Duration(minutes: 10),
                                  speed: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                                  onTap: () {
                                    print("Tap Event");
                                  },
                                  text: ['The location is this: $_localAn'],
                                  textStyle: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontSize: 20.0,
                                      fontFamily: "Agne"),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: 1,
                                bottom: 10,
                                top: 10,
                              ),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(
                                        blurRadius: 4,
                                        color: Colors.black54,
                                        offset: Offset(2, 2))
                                  ],
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13),
                                  color: Colors.white),
                              child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                child: SizedBox(
                                  width: 1000.0,
                                  child: TypewriterAnimatedTextKit(
                                      pause: Duration(minutes: 10),
                                      onTap: () {
                                        print("Tap Event");
                                      },
                                      text: [
                                        'Its occurrence: $_problemaAn',
                                      ],
                                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                          fontSize: 20.0,
                                          fontFamily: "Agne"),
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                                      curve: Curves.linear),
                                ),
                              )),
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            child: _imagemAn != null
                                ? Image.file(
                                    _imagemAn,
                                    fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                  )
                                : Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                      '',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                      blurRadius: 1,
                                      color: Colors.transparent,
                                      offset: Offset(1, 1))
                                ],
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                color: Colors.transparent),
                          ),Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            child: _imagemGaleriaAn != null
                                ? Image.file(
                                    _imagemGaleriaAn,
                                    fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                  )
                                : Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                      'Capture a photo',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                      blurRadius: 1,
                                      color: Colors.transparent,
                                      offset: Offset(1, 1))
                                ],
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                color: Colors.transparent),
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              TypewriterAnimatedTextKit(
                                  pause: Duration(minutes: 10),
                                  onTap: () {
                                    print("Select below");
                                  },
                                  text: [
                                    'Need to edit your message?',
                                  ],
                                  textStyle: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                      color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                                      fontSize: 20.0,
                                      fontFamily: "Agne"),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  curve: Curves.linear),
                            ],
                          ),

                          //INICIO DOS BOTOES SIM E NAO
                          Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                    bottom: 2, top: 2, right: 55),
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                child: AnimatedButton(
                                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Edit',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    Navigator.pop(context);
                                  },
                                  width: 70,
                                  height: 40,
                                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                  shadowDegree: ShadowDegree.dark,
                                  enabled: true,
                                ),
                              ),
                              //ACIMA SIM, ABAIXO NÃO
                              Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                    bottom: 2, top: 2, left: 55),
                                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                child: AnimatedButton(
                                  child: const Text(
                                    'Send',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 19,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    enviarMensagem();
                                    showDialog(
                                        context: context,
                                        builder: (_) => AssetGiffyDialog(
                                              image: Image.asset(
                                                  'Assets/image/Correta.gif'),
                                              title: Text(
                                                'Success',
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontSize: 22.0,
                                                    fontWeight:
                                                        FontWeight.w600),
                                              ),
                                              description: Text(
                                                'Hi, we received your message',
                                                style: TextStyle(),
                                              ),
                                              entryAnimation:
                                                  EntryAnimation.BOTTOM_RIGHT,
                                              onlyCancelButton: false,
                                              onOkButtonPressed: () async {
                                                final result =
                                                    await Navigator.push(
                                                        context,
                                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                                            builder: (context) =>
                                                                splashScreen()));
                                              },
                                              onlyOkButton: true,
                                            ));
                                  },
                                  width: 70,
                                  height: 40,
                                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                  shadowDegree: ShadowDegree.dark,
                                  enabled: true,
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
                      ),
                    ]))),
      )
    ]);
  }
}
```